# Import website to xampp: htaccess changes

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, xampp

I have an Joomla-Website running that is also using the .htaccess for generating SEO-friendly URLs for example. Because of an upgrade I want to import the website to xampp in a first step. This works fine for the welcome page. But if I select a link from the menue I always get an "Object not found" error. This is due to .htaccess file. I have somehow to adapt it from www.mypage.com to localhost/mypage.

This is how the .htaccess of the regular website looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mypage\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.de/$1 [L,R=301]

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Now I have to change this so that is works with localhost/mypage instead of www.mypage.de. I'm not familiar with .htaccess so it would be great if someone could tell where the error comes from and what changes have to be done here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out how it works:

```
RewriteEngine on

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /mypage

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

The key thing is to change the RewriteBase to /mypage.

In addition to that I removed this part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mypage\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

As it only applies for the productive website on the web.